# Is it possible to learn Zend framework without learning PHP first?

Tags: php, zend-framework

this is maybe a silly question but I am really wondering if it is possible to use a MVC framework such as Zend without learning the language first? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's really hard to understand a foreign book about philosophie if you don't speak the foreign language.

Comment: @erenon It's hard, but there is a chance the first word you learn in the language will be something useful, not a swear word. :)

Comment: you are sooo ambitious I wish you the best

Answer (score 2):

You can't learn Zend Framework without learning PHP. That you might have guessed.

After, you don't need to have a degree in PHP to learn Zend Framework.
You can learn them both together.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: A framework serves to speed up development, by giving you a set of tools to handle mundane and repetitive tasks. Some frameworks also enforce a specific programming model, but their primary task is always helping you write faster and cleaner code.

Having said that, it becomes quite obvious that anyone thinking of using such a framework, first needs to understand (globally) the language it's written in. You don't have to know every available function by memory (who does?), but you will need to know the basics at least. As I said, a framework speeds up your development. It can never replace it.

If you write poor code without a framework, expect to write poor code with a framework.
If you can't code at all without a framework, then you won't be able to code with one either.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to lean MVC in general without knowing a programming language. Learning a specific framework will mean learning the language in which it's written. So, yes, it is possible to start learning Zend Framework without knowing about PHP, but be prepared to learn PHP on the way.

Answer (score 1):

I would say YES it is possible, but provided you have experience in other languages or framework. However you cant really go far, and you probably learn PHP along the way in exploring the framework. From scratch will be kind of tough though.

**To add:**

I was learning Drupal without actually learning PHP prior. But in the process, I kind of figured out bits and pieces of PHP as I've knowledge in other languages.

Comment: OK, I think I might start from Drupal as well. I am actually a designer and programming is not my strong point yet. I have learnt PHP, MySQL by myself in the past but never get any chance to practice and I have forgotten most of them. 

I have also learnt javaScript and unfortunelly have also forgotten most of it. The only "programming" I can do right now is jQuery. So o.k.w do you think I need to pick up PHP first before I dive into Drupal? And by the way Drupal or Joomla which you think is better? Thank you!

Comment: @littlewoods1978: Drupal vs Joomla is another topic for another time. Since you do not have vast experience in programming language, I really think you should get familiarised with PHP first. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.  You might find it slightly more difficult though if you're not familiar with the language.  It depends on how much programming/language experience you've had previously. PHP is a relatively straightforward language to pick up but obviously if you've not done development before with something with similar constructs and syntactical similarities, then you're going to struggle.

Zend can be a complex beast however, and I'd recommend at least playing around with PHP to start with so you get an idea of how the language works, before you dive head first into the framework.

Comment: This is my first time to post a question and I didn't expect to get help so soon and so much! WOW I must say I love this place! And thank you for all of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll struggle like hell, even if you do manage it. Frameworks are tools that encourage good programming standards and give you access to libraries for which you can call functions into your applications (to avoid writing everything or hard coding). If something breaks you may have to manually fix something, what are you going to do if you can't program to fix problems that occur within the framework (hire someone?)?

I suggest you go to the php website and buy a book on the language to get your feet wet. I suggest starting with the essentials of any language: variables, arrays, functions, methods, object oriented programming, libraries, etc. At least study those topics (especially OOP and write a small project with them) before messing with frameworks. Many use OOP and you will struggle if you don't even know how to program in the language, although if you knew how to program it would be less of a struggle than if you didn't know either OOP/Programming in general.

It's not a skill you develop over night, write code, read code, debug code, and repeat until you're familiar with the general concepts.